# Code formatting in visual studio for ASP.NET

Tags: visual-studio-2008, formatting

How can I have the same formatting as mentioned in this resource for ASP.NET. Like all attributes in separate lines as starting line.

Is it possible to format my code in ASP.NET? Please help.

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210116172353/http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2007/09/29/cleaning-up-xaml-code-and-improving-parsing-time-with-blend.aspx#lbu_note2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format functionality is available for both the page html and the code behind in an ASP.Net project.

Comment: But I want that all the attribute of an ASP.NET tag be on separate lines. How can I do that?